# File Picker 502 Bad GateWay nginx Error

Tags: filepicker.io, filepicker

I am using Filepicker and it was working fine before 3 days!

Now if I try to open the FilePicker window it simply shows `502 Bad Gateway error`.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated

Comment: Few days ago there was problem with js library hosted by filepicker. You might need to clear you cache for all filepicker domains.